# how to draw using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6

I need to draw a rectangle in which I want to place numbers of circles with the same size but different colors.

color of circle chance after 4 circles.

using python

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
draw.ellipse((100, 100, 150, 200), fill=(255, 0, 0), outline=(0, 0, 0))
draw.rectangle((200, 100, 300, 200), fill=(0, 192, 192), outline=(255, 255, 255))
```

ps- I am new to programing

Comment: Please don't use specific python version tags. Instead use pil/image-library tags.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this could help you a little bit further..

```
#Import the library
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#Creating new Image object for background. The color 'scheme' is 'RGB' and the size 500x500pixels
img = Image.new("RGB", (500, 500)) 

#Creating object from img to draw on.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 

#First drawing a rectangle from (x,y) to (x,y). With color 'fill=(..)' and border 'outline(..)' 
#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-rectangle/
draw.rectangle((50, 50, 450, 450), fill=(0, 192, 192), outline=(255, 255, 255))     

#Variables for the color of the circle/ellipse
r = 0
g = 255
b = 0
NUMBER_OF_PICTURES = 5      #Change this variable for more or less pictures       

#For loop to do it 'NUMBER_OF_PICTURES' times
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PICTURES):
    #Printing calculated color
    print('Picture: ',i+1,'- Circle color: ', r, g, b)

    #Add for loop here for printing 4 times. 
    #Note: There will be no difference in the output because they then are on top of each other
    draw.ellipse(((50, 50), (450, 450)), fill=(r, g, b), outline=(0, 0, 0))

    #Showing the image
    img.show()

    #Changing the colors with a calculation so to not exceed the '255' limit for the 'fill=(r, g, b)' argument of the circle drawing
    r = r + int((255/NUMBER_OF_PICTURES))
    g = g - int((255/NUMBER_OF_PICTURES))
    b = b + int((255/NUMBER_OF_PICTURES))
```

You first need to create an image to draw on. In this case it's a black background. The next thing is to make a 'draw' object so you can draw on the image.

The drawing function you gave works correct, but I changed the notation from `(x,y,x,y)` to `((x,y),(x,y))` to make it more clear. The first `(x,y)` are the starting coordinates, and the second `(x,y)` the 'stop' coordinates.

Also added some variables to change the color of the circles. At the end of the for loop this involves a small calculation because of the 255 number limit the fill argument has.

The for loop for drawing the circle 4 times I didn't added, but in the code it says where it needs to be. Maybe you can try this for yourself as a little excercise.. I also didn't fully understand what you wanted with the 4 circles.

If you need 4 pictures with the same circle color, then add a for loop around `img.show()` like so:

```
for j in range(4):
    img.show()
```

Please ask if you have more questions :)

---

### **Second solution because question was understood differently**

Note: Added more libraries, for random and math. There also are a few calculations involved, which could be done better, you need to expiriment a bit of how you want everything to look like.

```
#Import the libraries
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import math
import random

#Creating new Image object for background. The color 'scheme' is 'RGB' and the size IMG_WIDTH x IMG_HEIGHT pixels
IMG_WIDTH = 400
IMG_HEIGHT = 250
img = Image.new("RGB", (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)) 

#Creating object from img to draw on.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 

#First drawing a rectangle from (x,y) to (x,y). With color 'fill=(..)' and border 'outline(..)' 
#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-rectangle/
REC_START_X = 50            #Start (x and y) needs to be the same
REC_START_Y = 50
REC_STOP_X = 350            #Stop (x and y) needs to be the same
REC_STOP_Y = 200
draw.rectangle((REC_START_X, REC_START_Y, REC_STOP_X, REC_STOP_Y), fill=(0, 192, 192), outline=(255, 255, 255))     

#It depends on the number of cicles in one row and the number of pixels between 
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW = 16               
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR = 4

#Calculates the number of circles in one column and calculates the diameter. REC_START_Y and REC_STOP_Y determines how 'good' the cicles fit
#Cast to int because range(..) cannot handle float
circleDiameter = (REC_STOP_X - REC_START_X)/NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW
circlesInOneColumn = int((REC_STOP_Y-REC_START_Y)/circleDiameter)
print("circlesInOneRow: ", NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW, " circlesInOneColumn: ", circlesInOneColumn, " circleDiameter: ", circleDiameter)

#Calculates number of colors and generates 'random' rgb numbers between 0 and 255
#https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/random/how-to-use-the-random-module-in-python
numberOfCircles = NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW * circlesInOneColumn
numberOfColors = numberOfCircles/NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR
r = random.randint(-1, 255)
g = random.randint(-1, 255)
b = random.randint(-1, 255)

#Counter for the colors
colorCounter = 0

#Draw the circles from left to right and then starting on the next row
for i in range(circlesInOneColumn):
    for j in range(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW):
        draw.ellipse(((REC_START_X+(circleDiameter*j), REC_START_Y+(circleDiameter*i)), (REC_START_X+(circleDiameter*(j+1)), REC_START_Y+(circleDiameter*(i+1)))), fill=(r, g, b), outline=(0, 0, 0))

        colorCounter = colorCounter +1

        if((colorCounter % NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR) == 0):
            r = random.randint(-1, 255)
            g = random.randint(-1, 255)
            b = random.randint(-1, 255)

#Showing the image
img.show()
```

---

### Thirth solution for drawing 'little' squares

It's not as good as the other codes, has a few bugs, but it will get you in the right direction.

```
#Import the libraries
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import math
import random

#Creating new Image object for background. The color 'scheme' is 'RGB' and the size IMG_WIDTH x IMG_HEIGHT pixels
IMG_WIDTH = 400
IMG_HEIGHT = 400
img = Image.new("RGB", (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)) 

#Creating object from img to draw on.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 

#First drawing a rectangle from (x,y) to (x,y). With color 'fill=(..)' and border 'outline(..)' 
#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-rectangle/
REC_START_X = 50            #Start (x and y) needs to be the same
REC_START_Y = 50
REC_STOP_X = 350            #Stop (x and y) needs to be the same
REC_STOP_Y = 350
draw.rectangle((REC_START_X, REC_START_Y, REC_STOP_X, REC_STOP_Y), fill=(0, 192, 192), outline=(255, 255, 255))     

#Number of small squares. Needs to be ..^2
NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES = 4

#It depends on the number of cicles in one row and the number of pixels between 
#Note: NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW > NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW = 8              
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR = 16

#Calculates the number of circles in one column and calculates the diameter. REC_START_Y and REC_STOP_Y determines how 'good' the cicles fit
#Cast to int because range(..) cannot handle float
circleDiameter = (REC_STOP_X - REC_START_X)/NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW
circlesInOneColumn = int((REC_STOP_Y-REC_START_Y)/circleDiameter)
print("circlesInOneRow: ", NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW, " circlesInOneColumn: ", circlesInOneColumn, " circleDiameter: ", circleDiameter)

#Calculates number of colors and generates 'random' rgb numbers between 0 and 255
#https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/random/how-to-use-the-random-module-in-python
numberOfCircles = NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW * circlesInOneColumn
numberOfColors = numberOfCircles/NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR
r = random.randint(-1, 255)
g = random.randint(-1, 255)
b = random.randint(-1, 255)

#Counter for the colors, rows and columns
colorCounter = 0

#Draw the circles from left to right and then starting on the next row
#Do this NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES times
xMovement = 0
yMovement = 0
rowNumber = 0
columnNumber = 0

for k in range(NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES):
    for i in range(int(circlesInOneColumn/math.sqrt(NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES))):
        for j in range(int(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW/math.sqrt(NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES))):
            startX = REC_START_X+(circleDiameter*j) + xMovement
            startY = REC_START_Y+(circleDiameter*i) + yMovement
            stopX = REC_START_X+(circleDiameter*(j+1)) + xMovement
            stopY = REC_START_Y+(circleDiameter*(i+1)) + yMovement
            draw.ellipse((startX, startY , stopX, stopY), fill=(r, g, b), outline=(0, 0, 0))

            colorCounter = colorCounter +1

            if((colorCounter % NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR) == 0):
                r = random.randint(-1, 255)
                g = random.randint(-1, 255)
                b = random.randint(-1, 255)

    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1 
    columnNumber = columnNumber + 1

    xMovement = xMovement + circleDiameter*(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW/math.sqrt(NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES))

    if(xMovement == circleDiameter*NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW):
        xMovement = 0
        yMovement = yMovement + circleDiameter*(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW/math.sqrt(NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES))  

#Showing the image
img.show()
```

Comment: thank for that. but i want 20 or 30 small circle one after one with in large square box

Comment: thanks for you help... can u suggest me how to do the same color as matrix wise (consider circle)

Comment: Do you mean to make 'squares' 2x2, 3x3 etc. from circles?

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible. Try it yourself, it's a very good exercise. I would suggest dividing the 'big' square in 4 different parts (which all have a different color you specified). 
1. Create `for` loops to make the 'small' 4x4 squares. 
2. Place those in another `for` loop that loops 4 times (`range(4)`) and place the 'small' squares in the right coordinates. 
So, try it in little pieces and you can do it! :)

Comment: Added it to the answer. It has a few bugs, but I think it will get you in the right direction. Don't forget, there are many more ways to do this..

Comment: Just change the variables to something like:
`NUMBER_OF_SMALL_SQUARES = 64
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES_IN_ONE_ROW = 64*2          
NUMBER_OF_CIRCLE_WITH_SAME_COLOR = 4`

and
`IMG_WIDTH = 4000
IMG_HEIGHT = 4000`

and
`REC_START_X = 50
REC_START_Y = 50
REC_STOP_X = 3950
REC_STOP_Y = 3950`